# Solve system of polynomial equations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, polynomial-math, equation-solving

I have a system consisting of 2 polynomials, in 2 variables, with complex coefficients.
The general case consists of a finite number of pairs of complex numbers.

```
NSolve[{poly1==0,poly2==0},{x,y}]
```

in Mathematica works for lower degree polynomials, but the time needed to find all roots 
seems to be exponential, 2^deg. Is there an alternative to NSolve, which is more efficient?
In other language? The degree we're aiming for is in  the range 15-25, higher is better.

Comment: @Paxinum Difficult to comment without a concrete example. Well, actually it is easy to write a StackOverflow comment, like this. But it won't be terribly informative absent such an example.

Comment: @Paxinum Since you're dealing with polynomials, [Gröbner basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) would be a good tool to solve your system. In Mathematica, this is implemented as `GroebnerBasis` and the "Applications" tab has an example of how to solve a system of polynomial equations.

Comment: @yoda  Reduce and Solve use Gröbner bases to solve systems of equations

Comment: @belisarius Ah, I should've double checked!

Comment: Yes, NSolve use groebner bases. There is not much structure in the polynomials to take advantage of, they are the most general form of polynomials in 2 variables you can think of (all monomials present).

Comment: @Paxinum Since it is bivariate, it might be effective to take the Resultant with respect to one variable, then find all roots of interest in that variable and back-substitute to get corresponding values in the other. This may give rise to parasite solutions so you would need to check for validity. Could be faster than using NSolve though, especially if you only want certain roots e.g. real and positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a solution, but seems like lesser number of cores is better.
(Compared with 2,4 and 50 processor cores), and 64 bit architecture is 2 times faster.

All this using NSolve. System of 2 degree 17 polynomials in 2 variables took 24 hours to solve.

Comment: To reiterate, without posting a concrete example, you might as well be writing to yourself.